# Central extensions of orthogonal group by $C_2$

Tags: group-cohomology, spin-geometry, clifford-algebras, orthogonal-groups

Suppose $(V,Q)$ is a quadratic space for definite quadratic form $Q$. It is stated in [Pin groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_group#Construction) that there are two central extensions of the orthogonal group $O(V)$ by the cyclic group $C_2$, corresponding to the Pin groups (denoted $\text{Pin}_{\pm}$) of the quadratic spaces $(V,Q)$ and $(V,-Q)$ respectively.

Are these the only possible central extensions (up to isomorphism)? I know central extensions are in 1-1 correspondence with the elements of the second cohomology group $H^2(O(V),C_2)$, so I'd be happy is someone could provide a reference showing what this cohomology group is. Does $\text{Pin}_+$ correspond to the identity element of $H^2(O(V),C_2)$, so $\text{Pin}_+\cong O(V)\times C_2$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The cohomology group $H^2(O(V),C_2)$ can be identified with the second cohomology group of the real Grassmannian $H^2(BO(V),C_2)$. For $\operatorname{dim}(V)>1$, this cohomology group is a two-dimensional $\mathbb F_2$-vector space with basis the Stiefel-Whitney classes $w_2,w_1^2$. The Pin-extensions are those central extensions which give the nontrivial central extension when restricted to $SO(V)$, so they correspond to the elements $w_2$ and $w_2 + w_1^2$. Since the one-dimensional $\operatorname{Pin}_+$-group is the trivial central extension of $C_2$ by itself, it corresponds to $w_2$.

Comment: The other two central extensions are $O(V)\times C_2$ and $O(V)\times_{C_2} C_4$, where the map $O(V)\to C_2$ in the fiber product is given by the determinant.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're asking about extension of Lie groups, or of the underlying abstract group. The discrete $H^2$ is usually much larger than the continuous $H^2$.